# Grails throws ConverterException from Marshaller after using grails plugin

Tags: java, grails

I have Marshaller in my grails application which was working fine but after I integrated plugin in my application it is throwing error.Error is as follows:

> Caused by: org.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException:
>   Error converting Bean with class
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.SingleTableEntityPersister     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:84)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:45)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:66)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:67)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:45)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:67)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:67)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller.marshalObject(CollectionMarshaller.java:41)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller.marshalObject(CollectionMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:67)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller.marshalObject(CollectionMarshaller.java:41)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller.marshalObject(CollectionMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:67)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GroovyBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GroovyBeanMarshaller.java:39)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:45)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.ClosureObjectMarshaller.marshalObject(ClosureObjectMarshaller.java:61)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller.marshalObject(CollectionMarshaller.java:41)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.CollectionMarshaller.marshalObject(CollectionMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:45)
>     at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.MapMarshaller.marshalObject(MapMarshaller.java:30)
>     at grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:184)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:119)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.render(JSON.java:132)  at
>   org.grails.compiler.web.converters.RenderConverterTrait$Trait$Helper.render(RenderConverterTrait.groovy:22)
>     at
>   com.goglides.ListingController.feature(ListingController.groovy:17)
>     ... 52 common frames omitted Caused by:
>   java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range:
>   -1    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.substring(AbstractStringBuilder.java:935)
>     at java.lang.StringBuilder.substring(StringBuilder.java:76)     at
>   grails.converters.JSON.handleCircularRelationship(JSON.java:341)  at
>   grails.converters.JSON.value(JSON.java:176)   at
>   grails.converters.JSON.convertAnother(JSON.java:144)  at
>   org.grails.web.converters.marshaller.json.GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.marshalObject(GenericJavaBeanMarshaller.java:66)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does your plugin use `new RestBuilder()` from `org.grails:grails-datastore-rest-client` plugin? Then you are most likely triggering [this bug in Grails](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/864). I just tripped over that problem again in our code :-(

Workaround: you'll have to rewrite your plugin code to look like this:

```groovy
RestBuilder rest = new RestBuilder(
        ...
        // workaround for https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/864
        registerConverters: false
    )
```

**CAVEAT** if your code relies on the converters being available for the body content, then you'll have to rewrite your code to handle the conversion manually. I.e. from

```groovy
new RestBuilder(...)
    .put(...) {
        ...
        body object as JSON
    }
```

to

```groovy
String json = (object as JSON).toString()
new RestBuilder(
        ...
        // workaround for https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/864
        registerConverters: false
    )
    .put(...) {
        ...
        body json
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What plugin are you using and is it compatible with the version of grails your using? You can also try a `grails clean` and restart.

Comment: The plugin is self made and have used the same version of grails as in main application.grails clean didnot work

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing `new RestBuilder()` to use `new RestBuilder(registerConverters: false)` and this appears to fix the issue for us.